# SQL Not In sub Query

Tags: sql

I have a situation where I need to select prospects (relationship of 'P') from our MEMBERS table for a particular site. However, when I select these people, I need to exclude two groups of those prospects. Each of these groups have entries in a separate table named MEMBERUDFS. Now not all entries in the MEMBERS table will have an entry in the MEMBERUDFS table. Therefore, I tried to exclude those groups from the main query by using two "NOT IN" subqueries but that does not seem to work. I am able to isolate the exclusion group with the following queries:

```
SELECT  MEMBERS_1.memid
FROM MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1
JOIN SITES AS SITES_1 ON MEMBERS_1.siteid = SITES_1.siteid
LEFT JOIN MEMBERUDFS AS MEMBERUDFS_1 ON MEMBERS_1.memid = MEMBERUDFS_1.memid
JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS AS MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1 ON MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1.udfid
WHERE (MEMBERS_1.relationship = 'P')
    AND (MEMBERS_1.email <> '')
    AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = '26')
    AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfvalue = 'No')
    AND (MEMBERS_1.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()))
    AND (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite)
```

And This query:

```
SELECT  MEMBERS_2.memid
FROM MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_2
JOIN SITES AS SITES_2 ON MEMBERS_2.siteid = SITES_2.siteid
LEFT JOIN MEMBERUDFS AS MEMBERUDFS_2 ON MEMBERS_2.memid = MEMBERUDFS_2.memid
JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS AS MEMBERUDFSETUPS_2 ON MEMBERUDFS_2.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS_2.udfid
WHERE (MEMBERS_2.relationship = 'P')
    AND (MEMBERS_2.email <> '')
    AND (MEMBERUDFS_2.udfid = '25')
    AND (MEMBERUDFS_2.udfvalue = 'Yes')
    AND (MEMBERS_2.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE()))
    AND (MEMBERS_2.siteid = @rvSite)
```

SO THIS IS WHAT I HAD PUT TOGETHER, BUT IT DOES NOT ELIMINATE THE TWO SUBQUERY GROUPS:

```
SELECT  MEMBERS.scancode,
        MEMBERS.memid,
        MEMBERS.fname,
        MEMBERS.lname,
        MEMBERS.relationship,
        MEMBERS.status,
        MEMBERS.email,
        MEMBERS.entrydate,
        SITES.sitename
FROM MEMBERS
JOIN SITES ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid
WHERE (MEMBERS.relationship = 'P')
    AND (MEMBERS.email <> '')
    AND (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite)
    AND (MEMBERS.memid NOT IN (
        SELECT MEMBERS_1.memid
        FROM MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1
        JOIN SITES AS SITES_1 ON MEMBERS_1.siteid = SITES_1.siteid
        LEFT JOIN MEMBERUDFS AS MEMBERUDFS_1 ON MEMBERS_1.memid = MEMBERUDFS_1.memid
        JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS AS MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1 ON MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1.udfid
        WHERE (MEMBERS_1.relationship = 'P')
            AND (MEMBERS_1.email <> '')
            AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = '26')
            AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfvalue = 'No')
            AND (MEMBERS_1.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()))
            AND (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite))
    )
    AND (MEMBERS.memid NOT IN (
        SELECT MEMBERS_2.memid
        FROM MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_2
        JOIN SITES AS SITES_2 ON MEMBERS_2.siteid = SITES_2.siteid
        LEFT JOIN MEMBERUDFS AS MEMBERUDFS_2 ON MEMBERS_2.memid = MEMBERUDFS_2.memid
        JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS AS MEMBERUDFSETUPS_2 ON MEMBERUDFS_2.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS_2.udfid
        WHERE (MEMBERS_2.relationship = 'P')
            AND (MEMBERS_2.email <> '')
            AND (MEMBERUDFS_2.udfid = '25')
            AND (MEMBERUDFS_2.udfvalue = 'Yes')
            AND (MEMBERS_2.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE()))
            AND (MEMBERS_2.siteid = @rvSite))
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You really need to use the Code Formatter.  The way you have your SQL - it is a jumbled mess.

Comment: Consider working on your indentation.  Also, we would need to know what the actual problem is and the desired output.  Some sample rows of your tables would be great.

Comment: You probably want some variation of [Left Excluding JOIN](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to play with your where clause...

```
 AND (MEMBERS.memid NOT IN (
    SELECT MEMBERS_1.memid
    FROM MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1
    JOIN SITES AS SITES_1 ON MEMBERS_1.siteid = SITES_1.siteid
    LEFT JOIN MEMBERUDFS AS MEMBERUDFS_1 ON MEMBERS_1.memid = MEMBERUDFS_1.memid
    JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS AS MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1 ON MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS_1.udfid
    WHERE (MEMBERS_1.relationship = 'P')
        AND (MEMBERS_1.email <> '')
        AND (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite)
        AND (((MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = '26') AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfvalue = 'No') AND (MEMBERS_1.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()))) OR
             ((MEMBERUDFS_1.udfid = '25') AND (MEMBERUDFS_1.udfvalue = 'Yes') AND (MEMBERS_1.entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE()))))
```